# How to capture the local and external IP from the same computer?

Tags: java

I know it's possible to capture the local and external ip in java, but I wonder if can capture these  2 at the same time or associating local ip and external to the PC that is accessing my application.

For I am doing a poll form, which will be filtered by IP that is, the user can only vote once. So came up the idea of capturing the external ip and local the same computer in a local network and associates them.

Comment: IP is not safe to use here since it can change and thus you don't know whether the user has already voted or not (especially if the user can use multiple devices). You'd have to require a login to achieve that in a safe way. Besides that I'm not sure you can capture the "external" IP for a computer in a local network either you only get the external IP (which could be that of a proxy/router) or the internal one (in which case the call would not involve an external IP).

Comment: Forcing the user to authenticate to the system is not good for the user experience. Especially for the system que does not require authentication to use it. I'll find another way to do this filter without authentication.

Comment: what about including also mac adress?

Comment: How is the PC accessing your server?  Using HTTP / HTTPS?  Using a base TCP/IP connection?

Comment: The application is open to all. uses http or https.

Comment: The mac address is unique hardware but can frequently be changed in the same way that the local ip?

Comment: Are you using a REST WS / Servlet?

Comment: You mean capturing IP address from http request or inside javascript, rather than in java? Or are you actually running some piece of java code on client machine?

Comment: The mac address normally doesn't change since it is used to identify the hardware, but ofc there are ways to achieve that (or at least send a wrong mac address) - which would be considered hacking. The problem would be that each client would have to send its mac address and I'm not source you can make it do that. But even if that would be possible a user could still use multiple devices (e.g. PC _and_ mobile phone) so you can't be sure a user only voted once (but ensuring that might be hard anyways).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fetch the IP Address, we use the `HttpServletRequest` object's `getRemoteAddr` method. But this will give you only the exposed IP of the client, especially when the client is behind a proxy.

```
String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
```

The local IP of the client must be available in the `X-FORWARDED-FOR` header in HTTP Request.

```
request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
```

[X-FORWARDED-FOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For)

Comment: I think that a possible solution  would be to capture the o  external / local ip and mac address and associate these because mac it is unique and is hardly changed with frequency as the local ip.

Comment: You cannot find out MAC Address in Java. Best way would be to use the user's email address, which will mostly be a unique value. Mostly!

Comment: I thought in email address as an alternative too.

Comment: *"You cannot find out MAC Address in Java"* - Generally speaking, you cannot find it in non-Java programs.  The MAC address doesn't travel outside of the computer's local network.